# How can I store cradit/ debit card's info using Braintree Android sdk?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using braintree for payment gatway. And I need to **store credit/ debit** card's information in my app for further uses. I mean (**see the image**) **I want a checkbox just below the CVV edittext** and if it is checked and a successful transaction then I want that **braintree will save** the filled card's information so that I can use it for further means **if the same user comes again he/she don't need to fill again**.

So I want to know is there any option/methods in Braintree SDK so that I can remember or capture the card's info when user comes again.

I am following this [artical](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview)

[image]

I don't know its possible or not, if its possible then how I can store?

[This](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods/java) link seems useful

And I know that Braintree's Drop-in UI offers a complete, ready-made payment UI for a quick and easy way to accept payments. The UI includes a card entry form see the image, and I want a checkbox too so that I can save card's info so that if user comes again don't need to fell again all the information.

I want same as in image2 a check box saying **"Save this card for fast checkout"**

[image]

Comment: m also trying to do so...hope something comes up

Answer (score 0):

Use braintree **vault**, create payment method token. Your **payment method token** will stores all your credit card information. Using *payment method token id* you can get credit card information. For more details please refer [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods/dotnet).

Comment: can you please provide an example because im a new user.

Comment: I recommend looking at the official website getting started guide: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite late but it might be helpful for someone. Yes, you can change the existing behavior by adding below code

```
card:{ vault: { vaultCard: true, allowVaultCardOverride:true } }
```

Add this code in your drop-in create method